# difference between Map and hashMap in java~~

Tags: dictionary, hashmap, difference

I'm confused about the difference between the following codes:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numberMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> numberMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

can anyone explain it, please? Thanks~~

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll assume that you know OOP concepts so..to be short.

Map is an Interface.
HashMap is a Class that implements Map.

Edit as requested:
Interface, in our case the Map Interface is just a set of public function titles which any class that want to use it can implement it's own logic.
You **might** view it as a Template or some kind of "Black Box" that has inputs and outputs.

take a look here: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html]

HashMap class implements those functions to be a Hash in addition can add more functions.. `class HashMap implements Map`
there's a TreeMap which has it's own implementation. `class TreeMap implements Map`

Interfaces are good for a lot of cases one that comes to mined is if you wanna iterate over may structures that implements the same interface.

```
List<Map> someMap = new ArrayList<>();
someMap.add (new HashMap);
someMap.add (new TreeMap);
```

anyway suggest that you'll learn OOP concepts to really understand.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide some examples, thank you~~

Comment: Thank you very much, now I got it~